# Не создаётся список на основе массива

Tags: java

У меня есть 2 массива типа char, мне нужно удалить из них определённые символы, для этого я хочу сделать их списками, чтобы затем использовать remove(), но при создании списка на основе массива выдаётся ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

```
 char[] a = input1.toString().toCharArray();
    char[] b = input2.toString().toCharArray();

    List<Character> ababa = new ArrayList<Character>(a);
```

Comment: Экстрасенсов  тут нет

Comment: @Эникейщик, а они и не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы получаете массив примитивов , а коллекции не умеют работать с примитивами.
Мне кажется, что в этом случае проще сразу получит лист вместо ненужного массива:

```
List<Character> a = input1.toString().chars().mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Character> b = input2.toString().chars().mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что `toString` у автора лишний)

Comment: это да, но тут не угадаешь))

Answer (score 0):

> *У меня есть 2 массива типа char, мне нужно удалить из них определённые символы*
>
> ```
> char[] a = input1.toString().toCharArray();
> char[] b = input2.toString().toCharArray();
> ```

Проще удалить символы из строки без всяких преобразований в списки, используя `String::replaceAll`, и потом сгенерировать нужный массив:

```java
// удалить символы a, b, или c
char[] a = input1.toString().replaceAll("[abc]", "").toCharArray(); 
// удалить все цифры
char[] b = input2.toString().replaceAll("\\d+", "").toCharArray();
```

---

Если всё-таки есть желание получить список символов, то в связи с тем, что для этого и так придётся использовать Stream API, сразу же можно отфильтровать ненужные символы при помощи `Stream::filter` (используя "отрицательное" условие):

```java
char[] a = input1.toString().chars() // IntStream
    .filter(c -> c != 'a' && c != 'b' && c != 'c') // исключить a, b, c
//  .filter(c -> !Character.isDigit(c)) // исключить цифры
    .mapToObj(Character::toString) // Stream<String>
    .collect(Collectors.joining()) // отфильтрованная строка
    .toCharArray();
```